# Joomla - Cannot install/Update any extensions - Permissions?

Tags: joomla

I have the latest version of Joomla installed on my windows server. On the System information - folder permissions - all the folders are in green as Writable.

If I try to update an extension I have noticed it downloads the zip into the tmp folder but thats as far as it goes and I get the errors in the image

[image]

UPDATE:

found error in the php log:
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: extractdir in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Joomla\administrator\components\com_installer\models\update.php on line 449

line 449 is this:
JInstallerHelper::cleanupInstall($package['packagefile'], $package['extractdir']);

I have a feeling something somewhere is stopping it extracting the zip update - any thoughts?

- Error - Archive does not exist
- warning - Update path does not exist
- Message - Error uploading COM_INSTALLER_TYPE_TYPE_

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution is to check that log and tmp folders exists and they are writable by the apache user (www-data).

you can create those directories by yourself and change them in the administrator panel like bellow :

**System** >> **Global Configuration** >> **System** : Path to Log Folder

**System** >> **Global Configuration** >> **Server** : Path to Temp Folder

hope that helps !